# How to upload an image with dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can anyone tell me how to send a uploading file to a iframe using dojo?
I'v tried many plugin but none works for me e.g
`$.ajax()` , `dojo.form.upload`. Bt nothing sims to work for me. Thanks!

Okay i used something like this

```
dojo.require ( "dojox.form.Uploader"); 
dojo.require ( "dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFra me"); 
<form method="post" action="UploadFile.php" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" data- dojo- type="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Some Files" id="uploader" /> 
  <input type="submit" label="Submit" data-dojo- type="dijit.form.Button" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please show us exactly what you have tried (code).  This is really the only way you will be able to receive any detailed help.

Comment: The main thing is that i dont understand how to fix it, because many examples given are confusive!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to "fix"?  If you include the code you have written (narrowed down to the suspected problem area), it will be easier to provide assistance.  If you are looking for guidance with a specific framework, please reflect that in the question tags.

Comment: Okay i used something like this `dojo.require
( "dojox.form.Uploader");
dojo.require
( "dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFra
me");
<form method="post"
action="UploadFile.php"
id="myForm"
enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="uploadedfile"
multiple="true" type="file" data-
dojo-
type="dojox.form.Uploader"
label="Select Some Files"
id="uploader" />
<input type="submit"
label="Submit" data-dojo-
type="dijit.form.Button" />
</form>` bt it's giving me a blank page which i dont understand a bit!

Comment: Please edit your question to provide this code.  It's nearly impossible to follow in a comment.

Comment: I'm new here so i dont understand how to edit it into code. Please can you give me a tip?

Comment: Click the edit button under your question, then paste in the code.  More info can be found in the help section at the top of every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembering it being quite hard to find an end to end example (don't think I did end up finding one) back when I was figuring it out, so here's some snips of what I did to make it work (dojo 1.9).

Create a templated widget with a template similar to the following:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" data-dojo-attach-point="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="documentForm">
        <input data-dojo-attach-point="fileUploaderNode"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Instantiate your file uploader as such:

```
this.fileUploader = new dojox.form.Uploader({
                label: 'Select a File',
                multiple: false
            }, this.fileUploaderNode);
```

Then have a button that does something like this:

```
this.uploadButton = new Button({
                label: 'Upload',
                onClick: lang.hitch(this, function(){
                    iframe.post("someEndpoint", {
                        form: this.form.id
                    }).then(lang.hitch(this, function(data){
                        this._uploadCallback(data);
                    }), lang.hitch(this, function(err){
                        this._errorCallback(err);
                    }));
                })
            });
```

Then you need to be able to parse multipart/form-data on your server, save the document wherever and return an HttpResponse. Should you be using .NET 4.5 look at using Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync

Comment: Thanks alot bro. That works better for me!

Thanks again in advance!